# Create a Credit Card Web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, credit-card

I need to create a web service for school project, and  I need to verify that the Credit details was entered are correct. 
Can anyone help create this web service or provide some links with explanations ? 
I need to verify the credit by it's number, cvv and exp date.
In Addition I'm working with MVC.

Thanks in Advance.

**EDIT** 
Since I am not going to use real details, The only choice I have got is to check only the Credit Card number. What's the best algorithm for that ? and how I can determine the type of the card ?

Comment: It depends whether you want to do it for real or not.  If you want to do it for real, I guess an easy way to collect, validate and store credit card details would be to use the API of an existing provider, such as PayPal.

Comment: You have a couple of options. 1) DIY the validation by [using regex](http://www.richardsramblings.com/regex/credit-card-numbers), but validating the security code and dates are impossible - how could you know they are correct. 2) Use a third-party API such as PayPal. They likely have a developer account you could use for testing against. I'm not familiar with doing that myself though.

Comment: I recommend looking into WebAPI.  Create a controller with a Post() method that accepts the values you want to validate.  Validate them and return the results back.  You can call on the service using JavaScript/jQuery/Ajax and retrieve the results.

Comment: I am not going to use real details, it's just have to be according to the credits rules. Is there a way to use PayPal without charging anything ? just to check if the credit details are meeting the standards  ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514430 for some minor offline verification you can do. Mainly the Luhn check. You won't be able to reliably check the card type, but could make a stab at it.